# SQL Server view based on JOIN two tables - how to replace NULL values with spaces?

Tags: sql-server, join, null, sql-view, isnull

I'm creating a view for some external system. This external system does not work with null values so I want to change them to some more user-friendly, by example "".

I use this query to create my view:

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView 
AS
   SELECT 
       r.CountryRegionCode, r.Name, e.ExampleData
   FROM 
       AdventureWorks2008.Person.CountryRegion r
   JOIN 
       AdventureWorks2008.dbo.SomeTable e ON r.CountryRegionCode = e.CountryRegionCode
```

The result of this query is:

[image]

As I understand I can use [ISNULL](http://zarez.net/?p=2017) operator to replace NULL with space, but how to use it in my statement? How to do it right:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL (r.CountryRegionCode, 0) AS r.CountryRegionCode
     -- ..
```

?

**Update:** It does not understand what the `r` is:

[image]

**Update #2:** thank you guys very much! The final result:

```
SELECT 
    CountryRegionCode = ISNULL(r.CountryRegionCode, ''),
    Name = ISNULL(r.Name,''),
    ExampleData = ISNULL(e.ExampleData,'')
FROM 
    AdventureWorks2008.Person.CountryRegion r
JOIN 
    AdventureWorks2008.dbo.SomeTable e ON r.CountryRegionCode = e.CountryRegionCode
```

Comment: Is this ok for you: 
SELECT ISNULL(r.CountryRegionCode,' ') AS CountryRegionCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` is a table alias. If you want get column name `r.CountryRegionCode` need to quote them: `[r.CountryRegionCode]`

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView
AS
    SELECT CountryRegionCode = ISNULL(r.CountryRegionCode, ' '), -- COALESCE(r.CountryRegionCode, ' ')
           r.name,
           e.ExampleData
    FROM AdventureWorks2008.Person.CountryRegion r
    JOIN AdventureWorks2008.dbo.SomeTable e ON r.CountryRegionCode = e.CountryRegionCode
```

Also please note about difference between `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`:

```
DECLARE @a CHAR(1)
SELECT ISNULL(@a, 'NULL') /*N*/, COALESCE(@a, 'NULL') /*NULL*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(r.CountryRegionCode,' ') AS CountryRegionCode
```